# UI thread waiting for other threads to execute - Not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, imageview

I have read that the main UI thread in android should not call sleep.

However, my application needs to :

1. call thread1 from main UI thread
2. call thread2 from main UI thread.

Use the output (2 images) of the 2 thread, add them and then display them.

I am using Thread.sleep() so that the main thread waits thread1 and thread2 till they are done. However mImageview.setbitmap is not working after i call it in the main thread (after sleep).

can u pls advise me how i should do this?

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading in Android should be done Asynchronously. For this purpose, you should use the [`AsyncTask`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

For your case, you would for example create a taks to load (or process) those two images. While the process is running (in another thread, off the UI-thread), you could show a [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) that shows to the user that your application is currently busy (this is then done on the UI-thread).

When the task has finished, you get the results (your two images) from the task, hide the progress-bar and show everything to the user.

Despite the fact that a non-reacting GUI always has the feeling that your application frooze, if a UI-Thread is blocked for more then 5 seconds (which is a looong time), your application will be Force-closed as it is not "reacting" (and an [ANR](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) will be raised).

Comment: Waiting in an event handler is getting up there with 'my floating point compares fail' and 'how can I stop my thread?' :(

Comment: Another thing - if the GUI is blocked, there can be no 'Cancel operation' button.  It is incredibly frustrating and annoying to users when they cannot stop things that they started by mistake.  There is no excuse today for 'Hourglass apps'.

Comment: @MartinJames you can cancel a `AsyncTask`. This could be implemented with a button or the "back"-key.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just Thread.Sleep(). In the GUI thread, do whatever you need to to start the two threads/tasks/whatever and then exit the event handler.

Do not wait in GUI event-handlers!  Not in Java, C++, C, Delphi, anything.  Use an async task, or a Handler, and signal to the GUI thread.  Thread 1 signals that it is done, thread 2 signals that it is done.  In either case check to see if the data has been returned by the other thread. If it has, you have both sets of returned data and so you can add them and display them.

Do not wait in GUI event-handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Threads And Handlers for this purpose. 
Here is a small demo for this,

Create a **Handler** in your onCreate like this,

```
Drawable d=null;    

Handler handler=new Handler()
{

public void handleMesaage(Message msg)
{
   if(msg.what==0)
{
   imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}

}

};
```

And now call Your Thread like this,

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable()
{
@Override
public void run() {
   InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
   d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
});t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Here is how

1. Create the two image loading activities as Runnable tasks.
2. Execute them with the ExecutorService.
3. Use `ExecutorService.awaitTermination()`; for the main thread to wait for Runnable tasks to complete. Its documentation reads

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
>   request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted,
>   whichever happens first.

This is the Asynch way of doing it and I guess should be preferred.